# Django Form setting ChoiceField options as Form is called

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

I'm trying to integrate with an inventory application and allow users to add parts to inventory through a Django form. I can read from the inventory database but have to write through the API so based on what they enter into the a previous form I want to give them a list of available parts to add.

Here is my form, I set a few choices just as a default:

```
class PartForm(forms.Form):
    PART_CHOICES = (
    ('BT-J1KND-A', 'BT-J1KND-A'),
    ('BT-J1KND-B', 'BT-J1KND-B'),)
    part = forms.ChoiceField(choices = PART_CHOICES,required = True, label = 'Part to add to Inventory')
```

And here is where I set the choices

```
parts_list = part_sql(part)
#build choices
PART_CHOICES= [(p[0],p[0]) for p in parts_list]
form = PartForm()
form.fields['part'].choices = PART_CHOICES
```

It displays correctly in the template but when I go to hit save and process the form if it is not one of the default choices I put in it says it is not a valid option.

```
Select a valid choice. BT-J1KND-C is not one of the available choices.
```

How do I fix this to get it to accept the choices I set as valid options?

Comment: Approximately how many part choices are there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Once the request gets processed, it seems that your user input goes into an unmodified `PartForm`, using the hardcoded values.

In order to get the request processed correctly, you need to have a consistent `PartForm`

You can achieve this smoothly by modifying the field's `choices` attribute at initialization.

For example:

```python
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = (
        ('EXMPL', 'Example'),
    )
    field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, required=True, label='Example')

    def __init__(self, custom_choices=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if custom_choices:
            self.fields['field'].choices = custom_choices
```

And then, just remember to initialize the form correctly, with

`form = ExampleForm(my_custom_choices_nested_tuple, ...)`

You may also double-check where you're actually processing data (a `form = PartForm(request.REQUEST)` not mentioned in your copied code, I guess)

Comment: This got rid of the one error but now I have value error when I try to process the data.  ValueError too many values to unpack the line highlighted is the template line where I display the {{form.as_p}}

Comment: Oh and just for clarification the choices are being passed into the form as a list of tuples so I don't know where the problem lies exactly

Comment: `form = PartForm(request.POST)`  `if form.is_valid():`  always fails

Comment: finally got it working after messing around with the validation for a bit Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you programmatically change one of the fields on a form, I believe you need to call `full_clean()` on the form afterwards so that the changes get reflected in the form. We do this on an application I work on - here is the code we have modified for your example.

```
from django.forms import Select

...

field = form.fields['part']
field.choices = PART_CHOICES
field.widget = Select(choices=PART_CHOICES)

form.fields['part'] = field
form.full_clean()
```

Note that as well as assigning `field.choices`, we also re-initialize `field.widget`.

Comment: this too also got rid of the validation error but now I have a ValueError too many values to unpack

Comment: Interesting, we have this working fine in one of our applications, will paste some example code above so you can see how our solution differs from yours.

Comment: The problem is arising when I get to is_valid in the POST request it returns False always....